# Jquery form - get variable to pass outside functions

Tags: jquery, forms, variables

Simple form with an either/or option of choosing from a menu OR inputting text.

Everything is working in general. However, I'm attempting to disable the submit button until *either* input option is used.

I can't get a variable value to be read properly in the jquery and I don't know why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var allThere = false; //stop
 
//Either pick an item....
$('#selmen').on('change', function() {
  $('#theName').slideUp(300);
  
    var theVal = $(this).val();
    if (theVal) {
    console.log('Select value = ' + theVal);
    allThere = true; //go
    console.log('innerSelect = ' + allThere);
    } 
});

//Or type new....
$("#theName").on("keyup", function(){
    $('#selmen').slideUp(300);

    if ($('#theName').val() != '') {
    console.log('key value = ' + $(this).val());
    allThere = true; //stop
    console.log('innerName = ' + allThere);
    }
});
    
//check the variable...
//This reports FALS always
if (allThere == false) {
    $("#newsub").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //stop
    console.log('Base allThere = ' + allThere);
} else {
     $("#newsub").removeAttr("disabled"); //go
     console.log('Base allThere = ' + allThere);
}  

}); //end doc ready
```

```css
body { margin: 50px; }
input { display: block; margin: 10px 0;}
#newsub { background: #a00; color:#fff; border: none; padding: 10px 20px; text-align: center;}
#newsub:disabled { background: #333; color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selmen" id="selmen" class="drop">
<option value="">Pick One</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="theName" />
<input type="sumbit" name="newsub" id="newsub" value="ADD" />
```

If things were working correctly the submit button should turn red when a value is selected or input.

**The console shows the variable being updated within the functions. However, for some mystifying reason, the variable isn't being read in the bottom if/else statement.**

What am I missing?

EDIT:

Additional Info...

The form is loaded via ajax. I essentially have :

```
$('#formload').on('click', function() {
    $('#mainformholder').slideToggle();
    $('#mainform').load('_core/inc/mainform.php', function() {
      //The snippet above
    });
});
```

So, moving to a function outside of the `document.ready()` function is also problematic. (at least for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well because you are only checking the value of `allThere` once when the document is loaded. You must check it again each time one of the event occur as well:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var allThere = false; //stop

  //Either pick an item....
  $('#selmen').on('change', function() {
    $('#theName').slideUp(300);

    var theVal = $(this).val();
    if (theVal) {
      console.log('Select value = ' + theVal);
      allThere = true; //go
      console.log('innerSelect = ' + allThere);
      checkValidity(allThere);
    }
  });

  //Or type new....
  $("#theName").on("keyup", function() {
    $('#selmen').slideUp(300);

    if ($('#theName').val() != '') {
      console.log('key value = ' + $(this).val());
      allThere = true; //stop
      console.log('innerName = ' + allThere);
      checkValidity(allThere);
    }
  });

  checkValidity(allThere);

  function checkValidity(allThere) {
    //check the variable...
    //This reports FALS always
    if (allThere == false) {
      $("#newsub").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //stop
      console.log('Base allThere = ' + allThere);
    } else {
      $("#newsub").removeAttr("disabled"); //go
      console.log('Base allThere = ' + allThere);
    }
  }

}); //end doc ready
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#newsub {
  background: #a00;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#newsub:disabled {
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selmen" id="selmen" class="drop">
<option value="">Pick One</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="theName" />
<input type="sumbit" name="newsub" id="newsub" value="ADD" />
```

Comment: That makes sense.... however, something I didn't mention which seems to also be a hurdle. The form is loaded via the `load()` function. Please see question Edit. I've tried moving the function to various locations and altering the target to more be specific, but still can't get this working. Thanks.

Comment: Well, then just put the function *inside* document.ready. See my edited answer. Javascript is pretty lax like that xD

Comment: Thank you.. actually moronic omission on my part. Was't running the function within the if/else statements that alter the variable. This solves it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AVAVT here's my overall solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var flds = 0; //count

  //Either pick an item....
  $('#selmen').on('change', function() {
    $('#theName').slideUp(300);

    var theVal = $(this).val();
    if (theVal) {
      console.log('Select value = ' + theVal);
      flds++; //go
      checkValidity(flds);
    }
  });

  //Or type new....
  $("#theName").on("blur", function() {
    $('#selmen').slideUp(300);

    if ($('#theName').val() != '') {
      console.log('key value = ' + $(this).val());
      flds++; //go
      checkValidity(flds);
    }
  });

  //Or type new....
  $("#other").on("blur", function() {
    if ($('#other').val() != '') {
      console.log('key value = ' + $(this).val());
      flds++; //go
      checkValidity(flds);
    }
  });

  checkValidity(flds);

  function checkValidity(flds) {
    if (flds < 2) {
      $("#newsub").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //stop
      console.clear();
      console.log('Base fld count = ' + flds);
    } else {
      $("#newsub").removeAttr("disabled"); //go
      console.clear();
      console.log('Base fld count = ' + flds);
    }
  }

}); //end doc ready
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#newsub {
  background: #a00;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#newsub:disabled {
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selmen" id="selmen" class="drop">
<option value="">Pick One</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="theName" />
<input type="text" id="other" />
<input type="sumbit" name="newsub" id="newsub" value="ADD" />
```

Basically, I have several fields like this. So, by adding to a count variable I can determine how many fields are filled in and enable the submit button that way. Essentially if I know there are 5 fields which are required, I can count them. This allows me to circumvent issues encountered by setting the either/or select/inputs fields as "required".

Added additional field so the submit should now be enabled only after both items are completed. And changed `keyup` to `blur` in the input field functions.

(further individual input validation not included here for simplicity).